# PayPal Guest Checkout for Recurring Payments in Sandbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I'm working on an update on my current system with PayPal ExpressCheckout to allow users to pay without PayPal accounts. 
I added the

```
SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.SolutionType = SolutionTypeType.SOLE;
//Not sure If I need this one
SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.LandingPage = LandingPageType.BILLING;
```

For Merchant Account setting
I activated Enhanced Recurring Payments in the Sandbox Recurring Payment and turn the PayPal account optional in the website preference.

I do not know why the Guest checkout still not showing up.
Did i missed something?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks PP_Punna but it seems the website payment standard require me to create a button in PayPal and user pay thought that link. In that case how do I associate the payment with my user accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enhanced Recurring Payment option is applicable for PayPal website payment standard. So you will need to use PayPal [Subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_step_1/) button with Enhanced Recurring Payment option for receiving recurring payments and allow the buyer to make guest payment. Enhanced Recurring Payment option doesn't work with PayPal Express Checkout.

Comment: Thanks PP_Punna but it seems the website payment standard require me to create a button in PayPal and user pay thought that link. In that case how do I associate the payment with my user accounts?

Comment: When you create a button in your PayPal account, the button code will point to your PayPal account. If a buyer makes payment with that button then the payment will move to your PayPal account,

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean how do I associate the payers with their user accounts in my website when they use Credit Card payment.

Comment: Use PayPal IPN, so that for every subscription creation, subscripiton payment you will get the IPN data from PayPal. Copy the email address of the buyer and use this email address at your website for managing the user customer information at your end.

Comment: That is what I did earlier but if client use different emails there would be issue. And I believe when client pay with Credit Card the e-mail might not be the same or required. And right now I am trying with billing plans but it require me to provide the Credit Card information which I want Clients to put in PayPal directly. Looking for a way to work around it.